# Spring Kafka Retry Logging

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have  a requirement to consume from a  kafka topic,do some work on records and produce to another topic with spring-kafka 2.1.7.Other requiremenrs are transactional for once only semantics,retry and error handling.On failure to commit a record  I should do 3 retries ,log each of the retry messaage to retry topic anf on failure of all retries send the record to a dead letter topic . I looked at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/575 and it  has excellent details on solving the  problem. The thing that I am struggling with is how to log each of the retry message with details like consumer offset ,topic it was trying to commit,etc .Is there a way to  get these from retry call back ?. The retrylistener snippet below is registered with a org.springframework.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler that is set as container property to ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory ?

```
         @Bean
         public RetryListener retryListener(KafkaTemplate<String,SpecificRecord> kafkaTemplate) {
             return new RetryListenerSupport() {

                public void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback callback, Throwable throwable) {
                    int retryCount =context.getRetryCount();
                    kafkaTemplate) .send(new ProducerRecord<String,SpecificRecord>("topic_name",record));
                }
             };
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RetryContext` is populated with some useful info in the `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter`:

```
context.setAttribute(CONTEXT_RECORD, record);
switch (RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.this.delegateType) {
    case ACKNOWLEDGING_CONSUMER_AWARE:
        context.setAttribute(CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT, acknowledgment);
        context.setAttribute(CONTEXT_CONSUMER, consumer);
        RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.this.delegate.onMessage(record, acknowledgment, consumer);
        break;
    case ACKNOWLEDGING:
        context.setAttribute(CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT, acknowledgment);
        RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.this.delegate.onMessage(record, acknowledgment);
        break;
    case CONSUMER_AWARE:
        context.setAttribute(CONTEXT_CONSUMER, consumer);
        RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.this.delegate.onMessage(record, consumer);
        break;
    case SIMPLE:
        RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.this.delegate.onMessage(record);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. That worked   nicely . I have  a case where  if I receive a particular type of exception from down stream , I should send a notification with a different message to another topic and should not do retries . This exception can happen  before doing the  producer.send() and producer.sendoffsetsToTransaction, so I am guessing this will not invoke the retry template  since transaction manager is not involved here .Would catching   that exception and doing an acknowledge work on this case ?. Idea is  to process the next record from the consumer without doing a retry if this happens.

Comment: That's correct. whenever you don't re-throw exception, but ack manually, there is no retry logic involved and you simply go to the next record for processing.

Comment: Thank you Artem .I tested this and works .I am not sure  if this question belongs here  but it   will throw it in . From reading kafka docs there could be cases where producer  gets an exception from which it cannot recover . What happens in these scenarios when using spring kafka . Is  a new producer created ?

Comment: Right, we have fixed that recently: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/753, https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/01/new-spring-integration-amqp-kafka-maintenance-and-milestone-releases